# Identification of D-Link firmware checksum and adding it to OpenWrt firmware

Tags: binary-analysis

I have [this D-Link](ftp://ftp2.dlink.com/SECURITY_ADVISEMENTS/DIR-605L/REVB/) firmware and would like to identify checksum type used on it and add it to OpenWrt bin file so I could upgrade firmware to OpenWrt instead default crappy D-Link. I did tried to update it through Realtek bootloader cli but it gave me an error

```
Booting...
OK
OK



---RealTek(RTL8196E-kld) version v6.0.4e(2013.02.22-18:00+0800) [16bit](380MHz)
P0phymode=01, embedded phy

---Ethernet init Okay!


**TFTP Client Upload, File Name: openwrt-realtek-rtl8196e-AP-fw.bin
-\|/-\|...|/-
**TFTP Client Upload File Size = 003AA004 Bytes at 80500000

Success!
<RealTek>checksum failed  80500000  00009fa5
```

Here is what binwal says

```
$ binwalk DIR-605L_v2.08UIBetaB01.bin 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11280         0x2C10          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2547712 bytes
658466        0xA0C22         Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 2.0, size: 89101 bytes, 8 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2017-06-09 02:24:25
748596        0xB6C34         Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 2.0, size: 2592128 bytes, 512 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2017-06-09 02:24:40
```

Answer (score 1):

1- If you own original firmware bin image you could use hex workshop, open it:
tools -> generate checksum, keep results. Also you have online websites with specific CRC algorythm, MD5, MDC2, and so on... Keep as much results as you could for next step..

2- Normally checksum bytes should be at the end of the file (EOF) and usually is a CRC32 (4 bytes lenght). So collect all checksums and take a look to results if match ok.

Then you would be able to generate correct checksum with proper algorythm, just in case as the bootloader makes.

Never loose the faith :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I have this D-Link firmware and would like to identify checksum type
>   used on it

it is MD5 Checksum:  d7ad0f50b2f82d60283a75dc63072a6f

```
binwalk --verbose  DIR-605L_v2.08UIBetaB01.bin 

Scan Time:     2018-10-09 13:28:37
Target File:   /home/training/Desktop/DIR-605L_v2.08UIBetaB01.bin
MD5 Checksum:  d7ad0f50b2f82d60283a75dc63072a6f
Signatures:    386

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11280         0x2C10          LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2547712 bytes
658466        0xA0C22         Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 2.0, size: 89101 bytes, 8 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2017-06-09 02:24:25
748596        0xB6C34         Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 2.0, size: 2592128 bytes, 512 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: 2017-06-09 02:24:40
```